# Centos 5.8 cant get past login screen

Tags: centos, centos5, login, gnome

I think I've messed up my system.

I've been using KDE for a while. Recently, I tried to install a software called gnome-connection manager. I downloaded the deb package, converted it to rpm using alien and installed it. A few seconds later, system crashed and I had to restart it.

After the restart, instead of the login gui, i ended up in a console, and I couldnt login to it. If I provide an incorrect password, it says the password is incorrect, but if the password is correct, nothing happens and it will ask for the username and password again.

However I can login as root and then 'startx' to get the desktop. I tried to clear the /tmp directory, cleared the .gconf folders and restarted several times. But I can only login as root user...

Can any one suggest a way to get into my normal user account?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the package as root and see if things clear up?

Comment: Yes, I removed the package, but the problem still exists

Comment: Have you suggessfully logged into the textual console.  You get to that using CTL+ALT+F1.  There might be some stuff in your local directory that has gotten corrupted and you could delete it and retry to login graphically.

Comment: I can log into the console only as the root user. Be it the GUI or text console, only root login works!

Comment: force a fsck on all the disks?

Comment: I did fsck on boot, didnt get any error messages, tried to login as a normal user and it wont let me in. I logged in as the root user again..